# Modified Jacobi’s theta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, functional-equations

Be $t\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$.
Jacobi’s theta function is $$\Theta(t):=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\pi k^2 t}$$ with $$\Theta(\frac{1}{t})=\sqrt{t}\Theta(t)$$
Therefore $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\pi k^2 t}=\frac{1}{2}(\Theta(t)-1)$$ has also a functional equation.

QUESTION:

Does somebody know, what functional equation does $$T(t):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty ke^{-\pi k^2 t}$$ have ?

Comment: No ideas, information, literature ?

Comment: You can find some information (not much I'm afraid) in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146139/what-is-known-about-the-sum-xn2-n, it is about the same thing.

Comment: Interesting  link.